# Does it matter if con.execute() is called multiple times?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

Consider the following (using dapper)
Example 1:

```
var query = @"INSERT INTO FOO (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Test')
INSERT INTO FOO (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'ABC')";

using(var con = connection)
{
    con.Execute(query);
}
```

Example 2:

```
var queryOne = "INSERT INTO FOO (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Test')";
var queryTwo = "INSERT INTO FOO (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'ABC')";

using(var con = connection)
{
    con.Execute(queryOne);
    con.Execute(queryTwo);
}
```

I am trying to understand if it matters which way I execute my 2 inserts. From my understanding con gets opened on the using statement and gets closed at the exit of the using statement.

Does it matter how many times I call `con.Execute()`? Is it better to just have it under one query? I am asking this for purposes of determining the design of my application so that I know if I should go the extra mile to try and get everyone under a single execute.

Not sure if it matters but I intend to use SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

No one can really answer your question because no one really knows how you evaluate "better".

One advantage of the single execute approach is that your application makes fewer round-trips to the server. In other words, there is less overhead and less waiting. If your app does not have a fast and reliable connection to the instance, that might matter **a lot**. One disadvantage is that your app might not be able to identify which statement causes an error if one occurs.

In addition, you can also structure a single statement to insert multiple rows - rather than creating multiple statements in the one string. E.g.,

```
insert dbo.FOO (ID, Name) values (1, 'Test'), (2, 'ABC');
```

Does that make a difference? A slight one, but you be the judge. These are simplistic examples and there is no single answer/approach that is "best" for all situations. And you do need to consider your transaction boundaries - do you want both rows to insert as a single unit of work (so if one fails the other is not inserted too)?